# How to use more than one textview within an ArrayAdapter for a listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to display separate items in a list row. So i use 4 textviews. But i use arrayadapter for my class extending Activity. Now i have to put the list of strings in a row according to that textview. How to achieve this? any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually I'm extending `ArrayAdapter` in such cases. Generally You need to override only two functions in the adapter - getView() and one of constructors.

The code of the adapter is following:

```
/** class to act as list adapter for rows List */
private static class FourTextListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataClass> {

    /** To cache views of item */
    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView text1;
        private TextView text2;
        private TextView text3;
        private TextView text4;

        /**
         * General constructor
         */
        ViewHolder() {
            // nothing to do here
        }
    }

    /** Inflater for list items */
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    /**
     * General constructor
     *
     * @param context
     * @param resource
     * @param textViewResourceId
     * @param objects
     */
    public FourTextListAdapter(final Context context,
            final int resource,
            final int textViewResourceId,
            final List<User> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        final MyDataClass item = getItem(position);

        if(null == itemView) {
            itemView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_texts_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text1 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.text2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.text3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text3);
            holder.text4 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text4);

            itemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text1.setText(item.getText1());
        holder.text2.setText(item.getText2());
        holder.text3.setText(item.getText3());
        holder.text4.setText(item.getText4());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Agree with this and you can also extends BaseAdapter as well.

Comment: which one to choose between BaseAdapter and ArrayAdapter in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617093/listview-and-arrayadapter-issue-how-do-i-proceed

Answer (score 4):

Instead of ArrayAdapter try by using SimpleAdapter.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sampleArrayList;
SimpleAdapter sampleListAdapter;

HashMap<String, String> sampleObjectMap;

for (SampleObject sampleObj : sampleList) {
    sampleObjectMap= new HashMap<String, String>();
        sampleObjectMap.put("value1", sampleObj.getValue1());
        sampleObjectMap.put("value2", sampleObj.getValue2());
    sampleObjectMap.put("value3", sampleObj.getValue3());
     sampleObjectMap.put("value4", sampleObj.getValue4());

        sampleArrayList.add(sampleObjectMap);
}

sampleListAdapter= new SimpleAdapter(
            context, sampleArrayList,
            R.layout.custom_list_layout, new String[] {
                    "value1", "value2" , "value3", "value4"},
                    new int[] { R.id.list_content_column1,
                            R.id.list_content_column2,
                            R.id.list_content_column3,
                            R.id.list_content_column4});

        sampleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> sampleObjectMapLocal = sampleArrayList
                                    .get(position);
                final String value1Obj = sampleObjectMapLocal                                       .get("value1");

                System.out.println("value1Obj : " + value1Obj);

            }
        });
```

In the above code the listView contents are populated using an ArrayList *sampleArrayList*
and so the items at any column could be accessed using key ("value1", "value2" , "value3", "value4").

Hope this would help.